# How do I stop form from automatically submitting? (Django/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, forms

I have an issue where my form submits even though I've not told it to (in Javascript). I have an event handler for the form button, which checks if the input is a valid integer above 0, and works upon that. The problem is that even if it finds this to be false, the form still submits.

Here is my form code:

```
<form id="case_form" method="post" action="/dms/create/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h3>Case ID</h3>
    <input name="caseID" id="caseNum" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID of Case to create" required
           autofocus><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="submitButton">Create Case</button>
</form>
```

And my Javascript event handler.

```
$('#submitButton').click(function () {
    numVal = $("#caseNum").val();
    if (Math.floor(numVal) == numVal && $.isNumeric(numVal) && numVal > 0){
        $("#case_form").submit();
    }else{
        $("#errorDisplay").show();
        //Code gets here but still submits once leaving function
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my first Answer :D

Try this.

```
<form onsubmit="return fnValidate()" ...> ... </form>
```

Javascript:

```
function fnValidate(){ 
    var numVal = $("#caseNum").val();
    if (Math.floor(numVal) == numVal && $.isNumeric(numVal) && numVal > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
       $("#errorDisplay").show();
       return false;
    }
}
```

When fnValidate returns True your form will be submited. when function returns false this won't be submited.

Good Luck !

Comment: Oh cool, but I'm curious why do you `return` as opposed to just calling the function? :)

Comment: Hi, When returns from fnValidate if value is True, then the form will be submited. On the other hand when it returns False, nothing will be submited.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved it...**

Apologies for submitting this question, I was trying to figure it out for ages, then Sod's law - as soon as I submit the question I have a "oh, that's so obvious" moment.

I forgot to put...

`type=button`

...in the button HTML.

Answer (score 0):

this was happening to me, I realized I had to put my commented code in these Django comment tags for them to stop firing: {% comment %} comments here {% endcomment %}.

Comment: This was published as an answer, but does not attempt to answer the question.